Dynamic SQL clause with SQL IN operator
I have an SQL template file that has the following clause:
 AND (%s = '' OR type in (%s))

Here is an issue, when value of type is say type1, query becomes
AND ('type1' = '' or type in ('type1'))

This is perfect. And in my JAVA code I use String.format to replace the %s with desired value and also have ' as provided in the string values.
The issue is when I have multiple values, say I have type1 and type2. Then my code translates this to
AND ('type1', 'type2' = '' or type in ('type1', 'type2')

As it is obvious, the first boolean condition syntax is invalid. I am trying to do this because in my use case type at times is part of the filter clause and at times it is not. How do I get around this? I can modify the template but don't know how/what to modify to get to solve this.

AND ('' in (%s) OR type in (%s)) maybe? Honestly why are you doing SQL injection anyway? Use proper parameterization (eg a Table Valued Parameter)

you can update the template depending on whether or not type is NULL or has values.
String types = "'type1', 'type2'"; 
// String types = "'type1'";
// String types = ""; 
// String types = null;

String sqlTemplate = "AND (type = '' OR type IS NULL %s)";

String sqlQuery = String.format(
    sqlTemplate, 
    (types == null || types.isEmpty()) ? "" : "OR type IN (" + types + ")"
);


Thanks. Was trying to avoid special handling in code if possible

What happens when you use what Charlieface suggested above, does it work?
